# Did the Vredefort Crater fill in soon after impact?

Tags: earth-history, meteorite, erosion, impact-craters

The Vredefort Crater is said to have been 40km deep and 100km wide. But what I'm curious about, is how long it retained that shape. Would magma have immediately leaked into it and filled it, for example? Is it likely the soil and rock around it collapsed into the hole? Or would it be something that took years or huge timescales to erode and fill?

It'd be really neat if it lasted to today, so you could descend into its incredible depths and admire its vastness.